# Getting direction between two coordinates using Google API directions

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I am trying to get directions between current location and destination coordinates. I have managed to capture current location coordinates and can polylines between them.But when I try to use Google map directions API it does not work. Can any one suggest me step by process of achieving this. Here is my code. Sorry if there are blunders.

The code in the try block does not work. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {

```
    // getting the current location coordinates
    currentLatitude = Double.toString(arg0.getLatitude());
    currentLongitude = Double.toString(arg0.getLongitude());

    dCurrentLatitude = arg0.getLatitude();
    dCurrentLongitude = arg0.getLongitude();

    LatLng Current_Location = new LatLng(dCurrentLatitude,
            dCurrentLongitude);

    Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, currentLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate updateCurrentLoc = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            Current_Location, 16);
    map.animateCamera(updateCurrentLoc);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Current_Location).title(
            "Find me here"));

    Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(dCurrentLatitude, dCurrentLongitude),
                    new LatLng(51.399191, -0.772394)).width(5)
            .color(Color.RED));
    try {

        HttpResponse response = null;

        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="
                + dCurrentLatitude
                + ","
                + dCurrentLongitude
                + "&destination="
                + 51.41642777550773
                + ","
                + -0.7500430941581 + "&sensor=false&units=metric";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: When I run it on my phone i can see polylines between mentions coordinates but no route map. Am i missing anything.